# faces-redirect=true in JSF

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I am using the `?faces-redirect=true` in my JSF2, since I would like to redirect the user so the URL will be changed.

In JSF1.2 I added `</redirect>` in faces-config.

In JSF2 I have to add to my url  `return home?faces-redirect=true.`

The problem is that I see `faces-redirect=2` in the URL, what I haven't seen in JSF1.2 when I used `</redirect>`

How can I use faces-redirect in actions without displaying it in the browser URL?

My Jar's list:

- antlr-2.7.6.jar
- aopalliance-1.0.jar
- aspectjrt.jar
- atmosphere-compat-tomcat-0.5.jar
- atmosphere-runtime-0.5.jar

- commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar
- commons-collections-3.2.jar
- commons-dbcp-1.2.2.jar
- commons-digester-2.0.jar
- commons-fileupload-1.2.1.jar
- commons-httpclient-3.1.jar
- commons-io-1.4.jar
- commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
- commons-pool-1.5.4.jar
- dom4j.jar
- ehcache-1.2.4.jar

- hibernate-annotations.jar
- hibernate-cglib-repack-2.1_3.jar
- hibernate-commons-annotations.jar
- hibernate3.jar

- itext-1.4.8.jar
- javassist.jar
- javax.persistence.jar
- jhighlight-1.0.jar
- jsf-api.jar
- jsf-impl.jar
- jstl-api-1.2.jar
- jstl-impl-1.2.jar
- jta-1.1.jar
- log4j-1.2.15.jar
- mail.jar
- mysql-connector-java-5.1.0-bin.jar

- org.springframework.aop-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar
- org.springframework.asm-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar
- org.springframework.aspects-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar
- org.springframework.beans-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar
- org.springframework.context-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar
- org.springframework.context.support-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar
- org.springframework.core-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar
- org.springframework.expression-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar
- org.springframework.instrument-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar
- org.springframework.instrument.tomcat-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar
- org.springframework.jdbc-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar
- org.springframework.jms-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar
- org.springframework.orm-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar
- org.springframework.oxm-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar
- org.springframework.test-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar
- org.springframework.transaction-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar
- org.springframework.web-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar
- org.springframework.web.portlet-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar
- org.springframework.web.servlet-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar
- org.springframework.web.struts-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar

- poi-3.2-FINAL.jar
- primefaces-2.0.3-SNAPSHOT.jar
- slf4j-api-1.5.11.jar
- slf4j-log4j12-1.5.11.jar
- spring-aop.jar

My web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
    <display-name>OnBoard</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <context-param>
        <description></description>
        <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
        <param-value>server</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:/applicationContext.xml
            classpath:/applicationContext-security.xml
            </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.faces.expressionFactory</param-name>
        <param-value>com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.faces.forceLoadConfiguration</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>facelets.BUILD_BEFORE_RESTORE</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>


    <filter>
        <filter-name>Security Page Filter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.mycompany.servlet.SecurityFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>


    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>Security Page Filter</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    </filter-mapping>


    <filter>
        <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    </filter-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Resource Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.primefaces.resource.ResourceServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Resource Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/primefaces_resource/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Does the other JSF 2.0 aspects work? It might be that your classpath is polluted with an JSF 1.2 implementation which got precedence in classloading.

Comment: What is JSF2.0 aspects?
I have jsf-api+ jsf-impl version 2.0.2
as well I have aspectjrt.jar since I use Spring

Comment: Uh, just JSF 2.0 specific features. The annotations, the new API classes/methods, etc, all which are thus not present in JSF 1.2 or older.

Comment: so do you have solution to my question?

Comment: Basically the answer is that what you observe is not expected - something must be wrong with your config.  Maybe post your web.xml, and a list of your bundled jars.  What server is this running on?

Comment: I can only answer this question if you answer my question. Does the other JSF 2.0 aspects/features/whateverYouWantToCallIt work or not?

Comment: yes!
I am using my beans with JSF2 annotations like @ManagedBean

Answer (score 17):

This looks all fine. Something else is disturbing it. Maybe Spring? I don't do Spring so I can't tell anything about it. At least, it works fine here with Mojarra 2.0.2 + PrimeFaces 2.1 + Tomcat 6.0.24.

To nail this problem down anyway, consider creating a brand new web project with *only* `jsf-api.jar` and `jsf-impl.jar` files in the `/WEB-INF/lib` and two simple XHTML files with a `<h:commandButton outcome="otherfile?faces-redirect=true" />`. Then add libraries/components/mappings step by step until you get the same setup as the original project. Test the working of `faces-redirect` during every step. Keep track of what you've added so that you know what may have caused this problem.

Answer (score 7):

That's not what I'm experiencing with Mojarra (the RI). If I return the following in a managed bean:

```
return "somepage" + "?faces-redirect=true";
```

JSF redirects to the target `somepage` view and the URL doesn't include the `?faces-redirect=true`.

What implementation are you using?

Comment: I am using Majora:
jsf-api + jsf-impl version 2.02