# f:param does not pass parameter or the parameter does not get set

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2, viewparams

I use `h:link` with `includeViewParams=true` to navigate between my list and view pages and make the view page URLs bookmarkable but it doesn't work.
Below is related portion of my code:

in layout.xhtml (my template):

```
<f:view locale="#{localeBean.lang}">
    <ui:insert name="metadata"/>
```

in Articles.xhtml (my list page):

```
<h:form>
    <p:datagrid var="item" value="articleController.items">
        <p:column>
            <h:link outcome="View_Articles?faces-redirect=true&amp;includeViewParams=true" styleClass="view-details">
               <h:outputText value="#{item.title}"/>     
               <f:param name="id" value="#{item.articleId}"/>
            </h:link>
        </p:column>
    </p:datagrid>
</h:form>
```

in View_Article.xhtml (my view details page):

```
<ui:composition template="./WEB-INF/templates/layout.xhtml"> 
     <ui:define name="metadata">
         <f:metadata>
             <f:viewParam name="id" value="#{articleController.id}" />
             <f:viewParam name="id" value="#{articleLclController.id}"/>
         </f:metadata>
</ui:define>
```

Further information:
I use JSF 2.2, ocpsoft rewrite filter, primefaces library, and `ArticleController.java` is session scoped.

I have tried the following:

1- I used `h:commandLink`; with this, the navigation worked but the URL didn't include view-params

Articles.xhtml:

```
<h:commandLink id="viewArticleDetails" action="#{articleController.viewArticleByID()}" styleClass="view-details">
    <h:outputText value="View Details"/>
    <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{articleController.id}" value="#{item.articleId}"/>
    <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{articleLclController.id}" value="#{item.articleId}"/>
</h:commandLink>
```

ArticleController.java:
    ...

```
private Long id;

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
    current = ejbFacade.find(id);
}

public String viewArticleByID(){                      
    return "View_Article?faces-redirect=true&amp;includeViewParams=true";
}

...
```

I expected the URL to be `http://localhost:8080/testApp/en/View_Article?id=1` but it was like `` `http://localhost:8080/testApp/en/View_Article ``

2- I inserted `http://localhost:8080/testApp/en/View_Article?id=1` and it worked in both cases.

Answer (score 1):

The `includeViewParams` parameter works only for view parameters which are already in the given view (in your case, *Articles.xhtml*, **where you haven't got any of them**). Just pass them as `f:param`. As you want to perform a plain GET request, your best is to go with `h:link`:

```
<h:link outcome="View_Articles" styleClass="view-details">
   <h:outputText value="#{item.title}"/>     
   <f:param name="id" value="#{item.id}" />
</h:link>
```

That way you'll obtain item's id at your destination page, but is not enough to have the url changed in the address bar. To achieve that add `?faces-redirect=true` to your outcome to force a redirection.

**See also:**

- [Passing parameters to a view scoped bean in JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20880027/passing-parameters-to-a-view-scoped-bean-in-jsf)
- [faces-redirect=true in JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2990399/faces-redirect-true-in-jsf)

Comment: I changed my code in Articles.xhtml to `<h:link outcome="View_Article?faces-redirect=true&amp;includeViewParams=true" styleClass="view-details">
                                                            <h:outputText value="View Details"/>     
                                                            <f:param name="id" value="#{item.articleId}"/>
                                                            
                                                        </h:link>` but it still doesn't work. Btw my bean is session scoped.

Comment: This way is intended to work with view scoped. Why are you using session scope for dealing with view specifics?

Comment: I changed my beans to view scoped and googled through this til now but it still doesn't work. The problem I think is that `f:param` does not set `item.articleId` to `id` and thus it returns null. Or it might be `f:viewParam` that does not set `id` because I noticed that `setId` is never called.